# ISO 8601 / Kibana datetime conversion

Tags: php, datetime, kibana

I have a datetime pulled from kibana in the format

```
2016-02-07T04:00:54.090Z
```

I am trying to understand what the `.090` part stands for? This seems to be an almost [standard ISO 8601 datetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (using `T` and `Z`) but I cant figure out if the `.090` relates to the time (microseconds?), the timezone (..no idea) or some custom value actually unrelated. It could be some sort of [combined representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations).

I am using `DateTime` to convert this. So far I have

```
$dateTime = new \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.???\Z');
```

I don't think it isn't timezone related (as I assume I would have seen `..Z +01:00` or such) but then I'm not sure if its microseconds since I would have expected the delimeter to be a `:` rather than a `.` and more digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the [answer is milliseconds](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-3-datetime-format/41365/2?u=derp).